# How to return a variable from a function that uses .get() from tkinter and use it in multiple functions

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am trying to write a program that counts cards in blackjack. The program should allow users to enter the number of decks being used, removes cards from the deck, and look up the probability of selected cards.

When I wrote the program, I first defined the functions that were being used to ensure that they were working, then I started working on the interface, then the integration of the interface and the functions.

For the first function create_decks, the function uses the user input (decks.get()) to create the number of decks needed. The issue that I am running into is that I need the user-created deck to be used in the remove_card function, and I need to allow the deck to be updated as cards are removed, NOT reset to its original state. If I create a deck each time by using the create_decks function in the remove_card function, the deck will be reset each time. But I cannot call the create decks function without first getting input from the user.

How would I change the create_decks or remove_card function? Looking forward, I also need the same deck to be used in the count_cards function. I am fairly new to python and have taken a couple of courses, so if there are ways for me to make the code more efficient, feel free to comment on that as well. I did not include all the tkinter code as I was not able to copy everything over in a clean fashion, and I am not sure if that is needed anyway. If it is, I can find a way to share it as well. Thank you for your help,

```
def create_decks(*args):
"""Updates deck to match the number of decks being used (ex. H = Hearts Suite)"""
    deck = {
        "H": ["A", "K", "Q", "J", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"],
        "D": ["A", "K", "Q", "J", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"],
        "C": ["A", "K", "Q", "J", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"],
        "S": ["A", "K", "Q", "J", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"],
    }
    copy_deck = deck.copy()
    suit_list = ["A", "K", "Q", "J", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"]
    new_suit_list = []

    # creates the duplicates of the cards
    for x in suit_list:
        for _ in range(int(decks.get())):
            new_suit_list.append(x)

    # updates the copy_deck, MUST USE COPY SO DICT VALUES DO NOT SHARE SAME ID
    for key in copy_deck:
        copy_deck[key] = new_suit_list.copy()

    return copy_deck


def remove_card(deck):
"""Removes a card from the deck"""
    copy_deck = deck
    dealt_card_suit = suite.get().upper()
    dealt_card_face = face.get().upper()

    # remove the card from the list
    card_list = copy_deck[dealt_card_suit]
    card_index = card_list.index(dealt_card_face)
    card_list.pop(card_index)

def count_cards(selected_cards, deck):
"""Counts the remaining cards, and gives the probability for each card"""
    cards_remaining = []
    for key in deck:
        for cards in deck[key]:
            cards_remaining.append(cards)
    print(f"There are {len(cards_remaining)} cards remaining")

    # fills empty dictionary with the results
    card_count = {}
    for card in cards_remaining:
        card_count[card] = cards_remaining.count(card)

    for key in card_count:
        print("{}: {} - {:.2f}%".format(key, card_count[key], (card_count[key] / 
len(cards_remaining) * 100)))

    # iterates through the "counted" dictionary and sums the number of cards
    number_of_cards = 0
    for card in card_count:
        # iterates through the selected cards
        if card in selected_cards:
            number_of_cards += card_count[card]

    print(f"The probability that you get {selected_cards} is {(number_of_cards / 
len(cards_remaining)) * 100:.2f}%")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()

    # Set up the screen and frames for the GUI
    mainWindow.title("Blackjack Counter")
    mainWindow.geometry("640x480")
    mainWindow.configure(background='grey')

    main_frame = tkinter.Frame(mainWindow, relief='raised', borderwidth=1, 
background='grey')
    main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # number of decks text
    tkinter.Label(main_frame, text="Number of Decks:", background='grey', 
fg='white').grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nw')

    # number of decks entry
    decks = tkinter.StringVar()
    deck_entry = tkinter.Entry(main_frame, textvariable=decks)
    deck_entry.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='ne')

    # number of deck button
    deck_button = tkinter.Button(main_frame, text='Enter', command=create_decks)
    deck_button.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='nw')

    # remove cards text
    tkinter.Label(main_frame, text="Remove Card:", background='grey', 
fg='white').grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='nw')
    tkinter.Label(main_frame, text="Suite (H, D, S, C):", background='grey', 
fg='white').grid(row=3, column=1)
    tkinter.Label(main_frame, text="Face (A, K, 7, 4):", background='grey', 
fg='white').grid(row=4, column=1)

    # remove cards entry
    suite = tkinter.StringVar()
    suite_entry = tkinter.Entry(main_frame, textvariable=suite)
    suite_entry.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='ne')
    face = tkinter.StringVar()
    face_entry = tkinter.Entry(main_frame, textvariable=face)
    face_entry.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='ne')

    # remove cards button
    face_button = tkinter.Button(main_frame, text='Remove Card', command=remove_card)
    face_button.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky='nw')
```

Comment: The return value of a `command=` function isn't used. The function should set a global variable that's used by other functions.

Comment: It would be much better to make your application a `class` and not use global variables. The functions you previously developed could be turned into methods that operated on various attributes of the instance, like decks of cards. tkinter apps are event-driven, so everything that happens in the application with have to be in reaction to something the user does, like clicking on buttons or selecting menu items, etc.